# git pull: why a specific branch is needed?

Tags: git

So I have a clone of a git repo. When I did
    git pull origin

it tells me:
    You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
    a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
    for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

My understanding of push/pull is that it's for the whole repo and not specific to a branch. E.g. if I have 3 branches branch_a, branch_b and branch_c. I do 'git pull branch_a'. Would I not have the changes from the other two branches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git pull`  is a combination of:

```
git fetch
git merge
```

where `git fetch` doesn't need branch specification, because it simply aligns your remote refs to the corresponding head refs of the origin repo (although what it does need is a remote repo specification "if" you have more than one remote configured)

but where `git merge` absolutely does need a branch specification because you are asking git to merge some branch into your current checked out branch

so when you say `git pull origin`, you're effectively asking git to execute:

```
git fetch origin      // Where origin is treated as a remote repo specification
git merge origin      // Where origin is treated as a branch specification
```

but clearly for the `git merge`, `origin` is not a valid branch specification.

Comment: `git pull origin` calls `git fetch origin`, not `git fetch`. This matters when you have multiple remotes.

Comment: @hvd - for multiple remotes, absolutely - I've edited to make this clear - thanks.